# go up one level in python code in emacs?

Tags: python, emacs

Is there a way to go up one indentation level in emacs for python code?

```
def foo():
  ...
  def bar(): # if I'm here, is there a way to go to def foo? 
    pass
```

Comment: Why do you want a function inside another function? Anyway, calling foo from bar works in idle, I don't know about emacs though.

Comment: @user2746752: There are many reasons you might want to have nested functions in Python, e.g. decorators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With python-mode.el call <kbd>M-x py-up RET</kbd> resp. <kbd>C-M-u</kbd>

It would jump to the beginning of "def bar" first, with a second call upward.

It's docstring says:

(py-up &optional INDENT)

Go up or to beginning of form if inside.

If inside a delimited form --string or list-- go to it's beginning.

If not at beginning of a statement or block, go to it's beginning.

If at beginning of a statement or block, go to beginning one level above of compound statement or definition at point.